# How do I install k9copy on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I have looked through all documentation, and seen that I need multiverse sources enabled, which I've done - I've reloaded (sudo apt-get update), but "sudo apt-get install k9copy" still gives:
E: Unable to locate package k9copy

Any ideas? Is this perhaps because I use Ubuntu, and not KUbuntu?

Comment: Possibly better fit for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Apologies! Will ask there in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the package that you are looking for was dropped long time ago, last entry is for quantal ( 12.10 ) as [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=k9copy) will show you.

Answer (score 1):

It hasn't been in the package repository since 12.10 (Quantal): http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=k9copy

Also, for future reference, this question belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).